# Getting class' method address

Tags: c++, class, oop, pointers, function-pointers

I'm asking you to help me understand this concept. Maybe I don't understand something, I don't know.. So I have this sample code:

```
#include <iostream>



class X{
    int a;
    public:
        void do_lengthy_work();

};

void X::do_lengthy_work(){
    std::cout << a << std::endl;
}

int main(){
    X my_x;    
    printf("%p\n", &X::do_lengthy_work); // -> does compile
    printf("%p\n", &my_x.do_lengthy_work); // -> doesn't compile,
    // error: ISO C++ forbids taking the address of a bound member function to 
    // form a pointer to member function. Say &X::do_lengthy_work
}
```

I saw this sample of code in one book. I thought that we can't get an address of a class' method unless there's an object specified from which we want to get that function's address. But it turns out we can only get a class' method address, but not object's method address. I thought everytime we declare an object of a class, it gets it's own method, with separate address. Also if we do something like this:

```
#include <iostream>



class X{
    int a;
    public:
        void do_lengthy_work();
        int b;

};

void X::do_lengthy_work(){
    std::cout << a << std::endl;
}

int main(){
    X my_x;
    printf("%p\n", &X::do_lengthy_work);
    printf("%p\n",&X::b);
    printf("%p",&my_x.b);
}
```

Example output is:

```
0x562446a9c17a
0x4
0x7ffe7491a4cc
```

Both class method's and object's variable address change. But the b's variable address does not change. It's always 0x4, 4 bytes further away from 0x00 because it's an int variable. But why it's address is so close to 0x00, but function's address is so further away? Also - repeating my question from previous code sample - why can't we get an address of a bound member function, but we can of a class' method?

So for example we can do this:

```
&X::method
```

but not this:

```
&object.method
```

I started thinking - can you correct me if I'm right? - variables from a class are initialized once when class is declared (thus we see an address of `0x4` when printing out an address of X::b), and then (uniquely) every other time we specify new object (thus we see `0x7ffe7491a4cc` when printing out an address of my_x.b), but methods are initialized only once and every object uses the same method which is always on the same address?

Comment: `&X::do_lengthy_work` creates a pointer-to-member-function. It's a pointer in the sense that it provides a layer of indirection for member function calls, but it's not a pointer in that it **requires** more data than a plain old pointer in order to support C++ syntax. I was going to write an answer giving more details, but there's already an accepted answer (posted only five hours ago), so I'm not going to waste my time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can basically think of `X` as being implemented something like this:

```
struct X{
    int a;
    int b;
};
void X__do_lengthy_work(X* this);
```

Methods are pretty much the same as a normal function just with the addition of a hidden parameter of a pointer to the instance of the class.

Each instance of a class uses the same methods.

It could be misleading to take a pointer to a method for a particular instance as that might imply that you could call that method without having to provide the instance which is I guess why the language doesn't allow you to do that.